# How to send data from a mobile app to a server on a private LAN, via 3G/LTE

Tags: android, cloud

I want to develop a mobile app that collects some data and sends this to a server sitting inside a Private LAN.

I have this working when the mobile is connected via Wifi to the same LAN the server is in. What are my options if I have to send the data over mobile data (3G/LTE) so that I can send data when I am outside the wifi range of the private LAN.

Some of the options I could think are:-

- Have a VPN connection from the mobile to the private LAN.
- Send data to a cloud app via HTTPS and this cloud app would do a VPN to the private  LAN (a little vague on how this would happen)

Are there any better option for this scenario. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure that you will not be able to do this on mobile networks. If I recall correctly, each cell tower has its own IP, and each device connected to it has a private, internal IP. However, I'm sure you could get this to work on Wifi.
Refer this one http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html